# Display date with Javascript function while updating URL

Tags: javascript, html

So I am doing something with my Arduino Uno where when a button is clicked on my webserver the URL appends '?feed' to the end of it (but is still the same current page). This is absolutely necessary for my Arduino sketch because this is when it knows to rotate my servo.

ANYWAYS.  However, I want underneath the button to display the date it was clicked. The problem with this is when the button is clicked, it shows the date for a split second and then reloads the page to append to the URL.

HTML & Javascript (sorry if it's sloppy):

```
<a href="?feed"><button onclick="displayDate()">FEED ME!</button></a>

<script>
function displayDate() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Seems like you'd have to pass the date as well, or use the HTML5 URI spec to adjust the url in the address bar without navigating or refreshing the page ...

Comment: When you click on the button, you are sent to a new page (even if it is the same page). So your code won't run

Comment: FYI: `button` can not be inside an `a`, that’s invalid HTML.

Comment: @CBroe: You are right.  Relevant spec is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element  "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)."

Comment: @MikeLyons: How would I go about passing the date in the function?

Comment: Well right now you're navigating to `/?feed` when you click the a, so you could add another parameter `/?feed&date=<the return result of displayDate()>` then that date will be available from the query string on the next page. Also, in my previous comment I was actually refering to the HTML5 History spec. which is in an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use AJAX request with combination of [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). Something like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('feed')[0].onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', '?feed', true);
    req.send(null);
    window.history.pushState(null, null, '?feed');
  };
};
```

```html
<button class="feed">FEED ME!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```